Are there publicly available measures of option-implied skewness and kurtosis?
As mentioned in the title, are there publicly available measures of option-implied skewness and kurtosis? (that represent the skewness and kurtosis of the option-implied risk-neutral distribution, preferably for European stock indices) Something like the CBOE SKEW index.
Some examples of data sources that could contain them might be Bloomberg, Yahoo Finance, WRDS etc.
EDIT.
The reason I am asking this is because my own measured option-implied kurtosis is unstable, which makes it infeasible to be used in a regression. Option-implied skewness is still stable, so a publicly available measure is not that high a priority as compared to kurtosis.
MY CALCULATION FOR SKEWNESS AND KURTOSIS

Obtain a set of implied vols (per moneyness K/S) and fit spline/polynomial; discretize vol skew appropriately.
Convert all IVs (from the spline) to RNDs via Breeden-Litzenberger closed-form solution.
With the set of RNDs, convert it to risk-neutral probabilities (basically PDF to CDF).
Generate a set of uniform random variables (URVs, bounded by 0 to 1) to simulate a data sample (the larger the set of URVs, the more accurate the measurement of skewness and kurtosis).
Using the set of URVs, find the one-to-one match with the CDF and the appropriate K/S.
Calculate the skewness and kurtosis across the set of derived K/S.

It is because of step (5.) that causes the instability of option-implied kurtosis.

https://www.cboe.com/us/indices/dashboard/skew/ this does not suffice?

The CBOE SKEW is for the S&P 500, not for European stock indices, which is why I wrote Something like the CBOE SKEW index, but not the CBOE SKEW exactly.

I'm not aware of indices other than CBOE Skew. Can I ask, if you have smoothed your IV, possibly/preferably expressed as a polynomial in moneyness, can't you calculate your skewness and kurtosis? Is this calculation that is unstable you mean?

@Frido, I added a section MY CALCULATION FOR SKEWNESS AND KURTOSIS, hopefully it clarifies, thanks.

I don't think you need steps 4 to 6, which could be the cause of the instability. If you have smooth IVs, then you have smooth options prices $C(S_t,K,T)$, from which you can deduce the probability density $p(S_T = K) = C_{KK} (S_t,K,T)$. Then you can calculate the risk-neutral n-th moment of the stock price as follows: $$ E[ S_T^n] = \int_0^\infty K^n p(S_T = K) dK$$ or a discrete sum instead of an integral with $\Delta K$ fine enough. I set $r=0$ here, you'll need to add that back in, which is not difficult. Does this make sense?

@Frido, I understand what you are saying. My risk-neutral densities are in K/S, so I suppose the $K, \Delta K$ should be changed to $K/S, \Delta K/S$? When I did it this way, the discrete sum doesn't change much for the skewness and kurtosis case. Do you have a reference for your formula? This is my first time seeing it.

You can try Bloomberg or OptionMetrics

@KaiSqDist Sure you can use $K/S_t$ in the RND but you need to be careful you are consistent, i.e. replace everything containing $S_T$ with $K/S_t$. Personally I'd just stick to $K$. Which formula do you want a reference for? The formula $p(K) = C_{KK} (S_t,K)$ is the Breeden-Litzenberger formula, and the integral expression is just the expectation of the n-th moment of a random variable.

On second thought, I'd not replace $K$ by $K/S_t$ as (stochastic) local volatility models (with or without jumps) are generally not homogeneous in $K$ and $S_t$. I'd just stick to $K$ and thus $C_{KK}$ if I were you.

@Frido btw I recognized your photo from your LinkedIn profile, if you are open to it, do you mind sharing?

@KaiSqDist Sorry, what do you mean by sharing? My LinkedIn account has been restricted for some reason and it's impossible to reach their support. Honestly, LinkedIn is getting on my nerves and I may decide to never go back to it.

@Frido ah I see, sorry to hear about it. I meant connecting on LinkedIn.
